# Auto create date - annoation - Codeigniter 2 and Doctrine 2

Tags: codeigniter, datetime, doctrine, automation, annotations

I am using Doctrine 2 with Codeigniter 2 and I would like to Doctrine automatically generate current date on insert in a given field in the table.

**CLASS FILE:**

```
<?php 
namespace models;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="workers")
 */
class Workers {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created_on
     * 
     * @gedmo:Timestampable(on="create")
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created_on;


    /** @PrePersist */
    function onPrePersist()
    {
        $this->created_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    /* Setters & Getters */
    public function setEmail($email){ $this->email = $email; }
    public function getEmail(){ return $this->email; }
}
```

**INSERT METHOD:**

```
$worker = new models\Workers();
$worker->setEmail($data['email']);
$this->em->persist($worker);
$this->em->flush();
```

Everytime I insert new record in table "workers", there is allways `created_on` field `NULL` instead of insertion date. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If i am wrong, correct me please. But i knew as if Doctrine does not support default. You do that in php level like

```
/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $something = "blabla";
```

Looking at your source code, i see that you are using gedmo extension for doctrine. Am i right? So you have got two ways to do this.

**1)Just using Doctrine, No Gedmo**

Read [this manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html) very carefully and you will notice @HasLifecycleCallbacks Annotations.

So you should edit your code as;

**CLASS FILE**

```
<?php 
  namespace models;

 /**
  * @Entity
  * @Table(name="workers")
  * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
  */
class Workers {
 /**
  * @Id
  * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
  * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
 protected $id;

 /**
  * @Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
  */
 protected $email;

 /**
  * @var datetime $created_on
  * @Column(type="datetime")
  */
protected $created_on;

 /** @PrePersist */
 function onPrePersist()
 {
     //using Doctrine DateTime here
     $this->created_on = new \DateTime('now');
 }

 /* Setters & Getters */
 public function setEmail($email){ $this->email = $email; }
 public function getEmail(){ return $this->email; }
}
```

**2)Using Gedmo**

If you prefer using Gedmo Timestampable extension, then just drop the function prepersist, cause gedmo is doing everything for you. I also checked my source codes. I hope i do not have wrong predictions here

**CLASS FILE**

```
<?php 
  namespace models;

 /**
  * @Entity
  * @Table(name="workers")
  */
class Workers {
 /**
  * @Id
  * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
  * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
 protected $id;

 /**
  * @Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
  */
 protected $email;

 /**
  * @var datetime $created_on
  * @Column(type="datetime")
  * @gedmo:Timestampable(on="create")
  */
protected $created_on;

 /* Setters & Getters */
 public function setEmail($email){ $this->email = $email; }
 public function getEmail(){ return $this->email; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you solution. I solved without GEDMO extension.. Thank you!

Comment: I use this default: `@ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"default":1})`

Answer (score 11):

For doctrine 2.3, use

```
/**
 * @var datetime $created_on
 * 
 * @Column(type="datetime", options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
 */
protected $created_on;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the followings:

```
/**
 * @var timestamp $created_on
 * 
 * @Column(type="timestamp", default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
 */
protected $created_on;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try as soon as I'll solve my new problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985676/codeigniter-doctrine-inserting-error-many-to-one-relation

Comment: When I try your solution, there is still error - http://pastebin.com/pC313P0S. Any idea?

Comment: the type has to be datetime, although it will be applied as timestamp with default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP... timestamp is just not a valid type!